# Imperial to Metric lenght

Tags: units, length

I'm from Metric based country and have an unusual for me imperial notation.
Google didn't clear that up for me so I'm asking it here:

I have a wall with measures: 10'7-1/4''
What's 7 ? is it tenth of feet?
The notation defies my metric logic, why is it even split to two parts here.
I know that dash stands for 'and'.

Here's the source but it's not necessary, just in case.
https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/564x/58/82/7f/58827fbc888cef4a8c92f71941979210.jpg

Comment: Looking at the source, my guess is it means 10 feet and 7.25 inches, so the ' means 10 feet and the 7 must be combined with 1/4 to give the inches, denoted by ''.

Comment: ' means feet, " means inches, traditionally, so this is 10 ft 7.25 in, or 127.25 in.  Imperial measurements would typically divide inches by powers of two, so 1/4, 1/8, 1/16, 1/32 and perhaps 1/64.  Below that, and in engineering contexts measurements are often in thousandths of an inch, which in the UK is called 'thou' and in the US may be called a 'mil'.  This is definitely not a physics question!

Comment: While not 'precisely' physics, it is a question that arises in physics...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ' symbol represents feet, so

> 10'

reads "10 feet".

The " represent inches, and the - traditionally is how they add on a fraction, so

> 7-1/4"

reads "7 and one-quarter inches".

The total length is therefore "10 foot, 7 and 1/4 inch".

The - just makes it so you don't read it as "71 quarter inches".

On a side note inches are weird, because 12 inches makes 1 foot.  It doesn't operate nicely on base 10 like metric units.

Comment: "On a side note inches are weird" - they were more sensible when there were also 12 pennies in a shilling. The price of something was the same number of pence per inch or shillings per foot! Of course the USA had the bad idea of keeping non-decimal lengths but changing to decimal currency, in various Acts of Congress between 1775 and 1792.

Comment: Incidentally there are some examples of "pseudo-decimal" lengths being used in the USA. For example Boeing used to design all its plane fuselages in sections that were exactly 8 feet 4 inches long - which is 100 inches.  To simplify things for the rest of the world, they now design the sections to be exactly 2540 mm long, instead of 100 inches ;)